# Defining iframe size in runningModal object for Journey Builder Custom Activities

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm extending a Custom Activity as described in the the documentation on [extending platform activities](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/platform/extending-platform-activities.html) and adding custom interfaces when the Interaction is in a running state (by adding a hover state for the Activity and a 'More details' modal).

This works well, however I have an issue with displaying my runningModal.html page which is displayed in an iframe within the `runningModal` object. The documentation explains that the modal's iframe is sized to 420px x 560px and can't be changed, which is fine. However the `customRunningModalIframe` class appears to have a fixed size of 300px x 150px, which is rather unfortunate. Refer to screenshot below.

[image: customRunningModalIframe]

Is there any way to override the width and height of this iframe in this modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately nothing the 'src' contains can effect the iframe unless there's a tunnel in use like window.postmessage.  I did notify the engineers of this issue however.